# What are the reasons not to use many RUN commands in a Dockerfile?

Tags: performance, docker, dockerfile

I've seen several Dockerfile, and i have the feeling that people try to avoid using `RUN` commands. But why?

So is there anything (but repetitive text in this example) to preferr

```
RUN gem install \
  jekyll \
  github-pages
```

over

```
RUN gem install jekyll
RUN gem install github-pages
```

Comment: See [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each execution of a `RUN` command creates a temporary container from the last resulting image, executes your commands, and saves the result as a new layer. Minimizing `RUN` commands both reduces the amount of overhead from these intermediate containers, but can also dramatically shrink the size of the resulting image.

If, for example, you do 2 run commands, one that downloads 1 gig of data, and a second that deletes that gig of data, your resulting image will exceed one gig even though it's not visible in the running container.

Therefore, when doing large downloads of cached files to do an install or build of an app and you cleanup that build environment when finished, it's a good practice to do that as a single step so the deleted files never make it into any part of the image.

One last reason is for the cache. If you need to pull a new version of an app from a package repository, you also want to update your info on that remote repository (e.g. `apt-get update`) before doing an install to pull the latest version. If you separate the `apt-get update` from the `apt-get install`, the update command may be cached from an old build and the install will attempt to pull old or non-existent files.

Comment: In my experience this advice is good for the final state of a Dockerfile, but not for development, where you end up re-running a single command a lot. Therefore I regularly put all my commands in individual RUN commands, and combine them when I push them to a primary branch. I should probably automate that.

Comment: Separate commands probably speed up debugging of a Dockerfile, but once the Dockerfile itself is debugged, pulling in the variable parts of the app should be saved for late steps to maximize how much of the cache can be reused.